# POST request a string to HTTP Url

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, post, request

I have tried to come up with a solution and can't even get a base code worked out.

I just want a simple way to take a string, example: 
"http://192.168.0.1/mobile/code.fcgi?serverId=1"

and send that string to a target IP.

So take the string above and post it to 192.168.0.67.

Thanks,
J

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests
r = requests.post('192.168.0.67', data={'url': 'http://192.168.0.1/mobile/code.fcgi?serverId=1'})
```